# Maximum number of rows in SQLite Database in Pycharm

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pycharm

I am trying to create a sqlite database for an app in python.

So far my database contains one table and it contains 500 entries already, I think. I say this because that is what the built-in database tool in Pycharm tells me. I then created another table to contain the rest of the data. I think they did not go into the table because it wasn't showing in the database tool. So I created another database to insert the rest of the data.

When I tried to delete some of the data from the first database it deleted but replaced it with some of the data I previously  thought hadn't been entered in the first place due to 500 rows limit. I did this in PyCharm and all along it had thrown to exceptions. The diver is used was the xerial driver.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get to put all the data in one table? The final table is going to have a little over 1000 entries.

Comment: Most *likely*, PyCharm shows you *up to* 500 rows. What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME` show?

Comment: In your PyCharm, the results are shown in *pages*. What is your default page size set to?

Comment: the result was from the select count query was 556, how do i reconfigure the default page size?

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/database.html (IDE Settings -> database, apparently). But why not just use the page controls to look at the next page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLite has a theoretical maximum row count of [2<sup>64</sup> rows](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html):

> The theoretical maximum number of rows in a table is 2<sup>64</sup> (18446744073709551616 or about 1.8e+19). This limit is unreachable since the maximum database size of 140 terabytes will be reached first. A 140 terabytes database can hold no more than approximately 1e+13 rows, and then only if there are no indices and if each row contains very little data.

PyCharm displays database results in pages of a fixed size; use the paging controls (the left and right arrow buttons in the result page toolbar) to page through the results.

You can adjust the page size in your settings, see [IDE settings -> database](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/database.html). I strongly suspect that the default is set to 500.

A more reliable way to count your current rows is to query the database:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <name_of_table>
```